# How to parse with parsec expression in haskell

Tags: haskell, parsec

Type:

```
data Type
  = Ttype 
  | Arr Type Type
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data Ttype = String
```

My code:

```
lchar = lexeme . char

parens :: ParserT a b -> ParserT a b
parens = between (lchar '(') (lchar ')')

symbol :: String -> ParserT a String
symbol p = string p <* spaces

typeParser :: CharParser () Type
typeParser = arr <|> tbool <|>  tbool
  where tbool =  Ttype <$> (show tbool)
        subtyp = parens arr <|> tbool <|> tbool
        arr = chainr1 subtyp $ try (symbol "->" *> pure Arr)
parseIt :: String -> Either ParseError Type
parseIt  = P.parse typeParser ""
```

**How to parse this type:** (A->(B->C))->(A->B)
Sorry. I am new to the Haskell language.

Comment: Could you provide more information? For example, what happens right now when you run your parser on the given input?

Comment: The line `tbool =  Ttype <$> (show tbool)` is very suspicious... firstly `show _` has type `[Char]`, so the `Ttype` is expected to have type `Char -> x` for some `x`, which it clearly does not. Secondly, even if this was a type correct expression, it is self-referential in a way that probably will not terminate. You probably want `data Type = Var String | ...`

Comment: ERROR:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘ParsecT [Char] () Identity Type’
                with actual type ‘[b2]’
    In the first argument of ‘(<|>)’, namely ‘tbool’
    In the second argument of ‘(<|>)’, namely ‘tbool <|> tbool’

test.hs:41:32:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘ParsecT [Char] () Identity Type’
                with actual type ‘[b3]’
    In the second argument of ‘(<|>)’, namely ‘tbool’
    In the second argument of ‘(<|>)’, namely ‘tbool <|> tbool’

`